# DataAdapter.Fill method TWO tables in query

Tags: c#, odbc, dataadapter

This may seem simple, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to fill my dataset when my query includes more than one table.

For example, if I had a query that was "SELECT USER_ID, USER_NAME, CREDENTIALS FROM USERS, CREDENTIALS WHERE USER_ID = CRED_ID" and then try to use the DataAdapter.Fill method it throws and error saying it's not a single group function.

My DataAdapter is = da
My DataSet is = ds

What I'm trying is:

```
da.Fill(ds, "USERS;CREDENTIALS");
```

or

```
da.Fill(ds, "USERS, CREDENTIALS");
```

How would I go about doing this correctly?
I just need to run a query that selects from 2 tables based on a matching ID, but I'd like it in a single Dataset so I can go through the results 1 row & column at a time.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused. The result you are getting back is a single "table". You are doing a join between two tables, sure, but you are not actually returning two tables. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I had a MAX function being performed in my query and I did not have all SELECT fields listed in the GROUP BY clause.

Added those fields and got it working.

Thanks to all!

Comment: Heh. Well, we probably could've given better help had we known that. :) Glad you got it working.